# Regex for a particular format

Tags: c#, regex

I want a REGEX to check format of the below string -
*{Any String with any number of words}* **[**{any year}**] [***R{any decimal number <10 with 1 precision like 2.5}*] [*{any string, Upper Case}*] [*{any string}*]
Till now I have come up with the following REGEX

```
/.*/\s[^\d{4}$]\s[R[0-9]+(\.[0-9]?)?]\s[[A-Z]*]\s[[A-Z]*]
```

but it only works for 
**[**{any year}**] [***R{any decimal number <10 with 1 precision like 2.5}*] [*{any string, Upper Case}*] [*{any string}*]. I am not able to get the first part right.
Eg of string - **One Good Day [1990] [R7.8] [XY] [Document]**.

Comment: can you define "valid year"? 44, 1515, 2037?

Comment: Corrected, Now could you please help?

Comment: `@"^.*?\[\d{4}\]\s*\[R\d+\.\d+\]\s*\[[A-Z]+\]\s*\[[^\]]*\]$"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
 # @"^.+?[ ]\[\d{4}\][ ]\[R\d\.\d\][ ]\[[A-Z]+\][ ]\[.+?\]$"

 ^                           # BOS
 .+?                         # {Any String with any number of words}
 [ ]                         # space
 \[ \d{4} \]                 # [{any year}]
 [ ]                         # space
 \[R \d \. \d \]             # [R{any decimal number <10 with 1 precision like 2.5}]
 [ ]                         # space
 \[ [^a-z]+ \]                # [{any string, Upper Case}]
 [ ]                         # space
 \[ .+? \]                   # [{any string}] 
 $                           # EOS
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
[\w\s]+\[.{0,3}[0-9]\]\s\[R[0-9]\.[0-9]\]\s\[[A-Z]+\]\s\[\w+\]
```

I am a newbie in regular expression, so please correct if any modifications are to be made.

Comment: That is an answer or question?